# Mobile (Android) jquery onclick design

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, mobile

I am using web app, for now it builds for Android Platform as WebView.

When I am using `<DIV>` tag, selected by jquery, with `on click()` function, i got blue transparent square when i click on it..

I tried to find some answer about it but i did not find something that fix it.

is there any chance to remove or redesign it?
Is there any chance to use jquery functions to show that the DIV is pressed while the finger is on the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a touch gesture is interpreted as a click

the touch equivalents are `ontouchstart`, `ontouchmove`, and `ontouchend`;
so: `$("identifier").on("touchstart", function() {/*...*/});`

Comment: Will it overwrite the blue square? do you know which transparent square i am talking about? Thanks.

Comment: I think and hope so, I got no problems with the active-selection-overlay this way

Comment: it did not helped.. i did `$('#menu_button').on("touchstart", function() { this.css('background','#096'); });` and it still doing the blue square.. any other idea?

Comment: cannot reproduce it. Add some more code which causes your problem (jsfiddle.net for example)